# Can Blue Yeti X (USB) play well with Audio Interface (Scarlett 2i2) for music?

Tags: audio-interfaces, daw, usb

I was recently given a Blue Yeti X, and I wanted to see if I could integrate it into my existing studio setup.  My current setup is a Scarlett 2i2, using Reaper as my DAW.  I usually plug my guitars and my existing mic into the interface without any problems.  However, when I tried to connect the Yeti, the setting that actually worked gives a horrible delay! Plus, that audio device setting in Reaper won't allow for any input from the analog interface.

I tried to connect the headphone out in the Yeti to the interface, but it gives off a horrible loud hum when you connect it.  So that's not an option.

Is there anything I can do to make all of these play well together?  It would be a shame to not use or waste this seemingly cool mic.

Comment: This is going to be more down to your computer OS than anything inherent in either the mic or pre-amp. On Mac, you could use an Aggregate Device as input [multiple sources bonded to a single 'identity'], though there's potential for two different latencies making this tougher, or the actual DAW software not being aggregate-aware. [It's not something I've ever actually needed to try.]

Comment: Like @Tetsujin said. Latency would be the worst of the different devices in the aggregate hypothesis. Not sure about other OSe's.

Comment: Scarlett stands no chance against Yeti.

Comment: Blue Yeti are not a microphone manufacturer I would trust with sound recording or music. They just seem to have waaay too many problems - they fit squarely in the cheap consumer market